# Yii transaction not rollbacked

Tags: php, exception, activerecord, yii, transactions

[image]i have the following piece of code and i pass it some data to generate an exception and test if the transaction rollback is happening. It seems it's not and i'm not sure why.
can someone help me? thanks

```
            $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();

            try {

                //.....

                //call private methods
                $category = MyController::saveCategory($params);
                $test_saved = MyController::saveTest($params);
                MyController::saveCommunity($param);   // here is an exception and it should rollback the transaction but it doesn't  

                $transaction->commit();

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollback();
                throw new Exception($e);
            }


            private function saveCommunity($param){

                  $community = new Community();
                  $community->user_id = $user_id;
                  $community->name = $name; 
                  $community->id = 71;  // this is a duplicate primary key and will generate an exception


                  try{
                      $community->save(false, null);
                  }catch(Exception $e){
                     throw $e;
                  }

                  return $community;

            }
```

(mysql tables are set to innodb)

Comment: i use mysql and i found mysql autocommit the create and drop table so the PDO can rollback anymore the transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code responsible for exception throwing:

```
          try{
              $community->save(false, null);
          }catch(Exception $e){
             throw $e;
          }
```

to something like:

```
          if(!$community->save(false, null))
               throw new Exception('Error saving');
```

And remove the exception throwing here:

```
            } catch(Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollback();
            //throw new Exception($e);
        }
```

Comment: still doesn't work. i tried this [one](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6659-cdbtransaction-is-inactive-and-cannot-perform-commit-or-roll-back-operations/) too and the same

Answer (score 0):

By default pdo doesn't throw exceptions and just ignores errors.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```